# How to avoid creation of foreign keys on Django Models?

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

when i create a model with a foreign key relationship, something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

when i do syncdb to dump those models to the DB it creates the table `post` and a foreign key to the table `user`. How can avoid the creation of that Foreign Key in MySQL. I hate foreign keys for different reasons.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Please guys, don't answer: "You should use foreign keys". That's not what i'm asking. I've my reasons not to use them.

Comment: What is the sql being generated by django for the above model?

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you hate foreign keys? Do you then manually enforce referential integrity in your code?

Comment: if you don't want a foreign key, you should start by not using models.ForeignKey

Comment: I want to relate models without the DB foreign key, so: @Roman yes, that is what my question says.

Comment: @Shawn yes, think in a DBA jr that doesn't realize that there's a foreign key with "on delete cascade" and deletes a tuple.

Comment: @santiagobasulto You're dealing with the problem in *completely* the wrong way. If you've got an incompetent DBA (yes, I would define anyone who does things without taking care to understand the implications as incompetent, as I can't immediately think of a stronger term), deal with that. Don't make a mess of your site.

Comment: @Chris. I can assure you that this things can happen. Not only DBAs, stupid developers too. Some bug. I've been working with DB (not only MySQL, but Informix and Oracle) for years and i've seen this things. You can't always control all the people on your company. Specially if it's a big one.

Comment: I once had a _friend_ who delete a directory and was surprised when everything within it disappeared too. I hate directories.

Comment: @santiagobasulto But don't you understand? As soon as you've deleted any of it, the data is broken. Avoid the situation in the first place. Deleting is extremely difficult to do accidentally.

Comment: Oh, and also, what's wrong with "on delete restrict"?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, Shawn. I know all this things. Irony is not good. I'm not an idiot. I'm just asking a question. Is it possible, yes or no?

Comment: "I've my reasons not to use them."  You had best **update** the question to  **detail** every one of those reasons.  There are no **good** reasons that I've ever seen.  I'd really like to see why this is important, because it violates the way relational databases (and the Django ORM) work.

Comment: @santiago We're not trying to insult your intelligence. It's just that without more info apart from "to prevent accidental deletion", it does seem like you're going about it the wrong way. All the questions are meant to detect/preempt XY problems (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't. Foreign keys are the right thing to have and you should never prevent the database from protecting its own consistency. If you need to do something special to the table (and are sure not to break its integrity) you can temporarily disable the checks:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0
# do something
SET foreign_key_checks = 1
```